# Solving the equation find the value of $u(2,t)$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> Let , $u(x,t)$ be the solution of the one dimensional wave equation $\displaystyle u_{tt}-4u_{xx}=0$ , $-\infty <x<\infty$ , $t>0$ , $$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}16-x^2 &\text{ , for }|x|\le 4\\0 & \text{ , elsewhere }\end{cases}$$ and $$u_t(x,0)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{ , for} |x|\le 2\\0& \text{ , otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>   For $1<t<3$ , find the expression of $u(2,t)$.

Here , D'Alembert's solution of the wave equation is $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x+2t)+f(x-2t)]+\frac{1}{4}\int_{x-2t}^{x+2t}g(\theta)\,d\theta.$$
where , $f(x)=u(x,0)$ and $g(x)=u_t(x,0)$.

As , $1<t<3$ , so $2+2t>4$ and so , $f(2+2t)=0$. Then , $$u(2,t)=\frac{1}{2}[0+16-(2-2t)^2]+\frac{1}{4}\int_{-2}^2\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}[16-(2-2t)^2]+1.$$

> Is it correct? Answer of the book is different , but I couldn't find any mistake.

Please help me detecting my mistake.

**Edit :** Options are :

1. $$\frac{1}{2}[16-(2-2t)^2]+\frac{1}{2}[1-\min\{1,t-1\}].$$
2. $$\frac{1}{2}[32-(2-2t)^2-(2+2t)^2]+t.$$
3. $$\frac{1}{2}[32-(2-2t)^2-(2+2t)^2]+1.$$
4. $$\frac{1}{2}[16-(2-2t)^2]+\frac{1}{2}[1-\max\{1-t,-1\}].$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you made some mistake in the limits of the integral. The bounds on $t$ means we will always have $|2+2t| > 2$, but $|2-2t| > 2$ only when $t\in (2,3)$. Thus we get

$$\int_{x-2t}^{x+2t} g = \int_{2-2t}^{2+2t} {\bf1}_{|\theta|\le 2}d\theta = \begin{cases}\int_{2-2t}^{2}d\theta & \textrm{if }t\le2\\\int_{-2}^2d\theta & \textrm{if }t> 2\end{cases}.$$

Does this fix your answer?

Comment: Replace the 1 in your answer with $t/2$ in the case where $t\le 2$.

Comment: When $t>2$, $2+2t > 2$ and $2-2t < -2$, so all of $|\theta| \le 2$ is contained in the interval you're integrating over

Comment: So finally $\displaystyle \int_{x-2t}^{x+2t}g=2t+4$..Is it??

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: It's $2t$ for $t \le 2$ and $4$ for $t > 2$.

Comment: @@– Anthony Carapetis) Please see my edit......

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: one of those answers is the one I'm giving you written in  a slightly different form. Put some effort in.

Comment: @@ Anthony Carapetis) Yes..I got option $4$ is TRUE..Am I right ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: right.